# PHP can't connect to database with mysqli_connect

Tags: php, database, mysqli, localhost

i'm facing with this problem that when i'm trying connect to database with constants, then it's showing this in my VS editor: Undefined constant 'DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME'.

Here my code:

```
<?php

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach($db as $key => $value){
     define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

?>
```

I tried change

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

to

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');
```

After this step, my localhost was showing this error below:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\db.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\db.php on line 12

Could you please help me solve this error, or tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, I also misread your code at first sight. Your computer seems to have issues resolving `localhost` as network host name. How you populate the array is not relevant to this.

Comment: For this particular case, you may ignore the warning of VS editor. (but why not do simple DEFINE statements instead ?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing it this way. Why not `define` them from the start? And your change to add ticks to the constants won't work. All you're doing is passing the variable names as literal strings

Comment: @Machavity sorry, but i'm kinda beginner in this, and i'm trying to follow tutorial and stuff. And this is more secure way to use connect to db. I'm trying to define them in foreach loop, that works. But when i want to echo one of those variables. It doesn't work and show that Constants is not defined.

Comment: I'd remove the ticked variable version and the errors from that. Then maybe try [getting the connection error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be an issue with the Visual Studio Code. The code works and connects to the db OK but shows DB_HOST etc as undefined with a wiggly red 'naughty' line. So I got rid of the warning by defining the constants without a loop or associative array.

```
define("DB_HOST", 'localhost');
define("DB_USER", 'root');
define("DB_PASS", '');
define("DB_NAME", 'cms');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're developing locally (with MySQL/MariaDB is available on localhost port 3306) on Windows, it looks like you need to determine which IP address you're using. In command line, try:

```
c:\>ping localhost
```

If your localhost is set up right, you will see a response like:

```
Pinging localhost with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Alternatively, you could check the following Windows file (assuming your main drive is mapped to `C`):

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Note that this file has no extension, and you will need to be the administrator for your Windows PC to make any amendments so use with caution.

Use the address stated in the reply from your ping (i.e., `127.0.0.1`) - if you didn't get a response then something might be blocking access. I had an issue where the ports kept changing because of a Windows Group Policy which was messing up my development locally, so I had to develop and test on a staging server which was slightly more inconvenient.

If you're using XAMPP, ensure that the MySQL service is running first. Check the `mysql_error.log` file and see what that tells you.

To find out the port you are using (in XAMPP) open the `my.ini` file from the control panel. Typically on Linux, this file is called `my.cnf` and could be located in `/etc/mysql/`.

The port to your MySQL instance is specified in your config file as follows:

```
port=3306
```

If this is not set to 3306 amend the script below:

```
<?php
    $db = [
        'db_host' => '127.0.0.1', /* or the ip address for your localhost */
        'db_port' => '3306', /* or the port specified in your MySQL/MariaDb config file */
        'db_user' => 'root',
        'db_pass' => '',
        'db_name' => 'cms'
    ];

    $con = new mysqli($db['db_host'], $db['db_user'], $db['db_pass'], $db['db_name'], $db['db_port']);

    if ($error = mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($error, TRUE) . '</pre>';
    }
```